# plyr's rename() working in R Studio if run manually, but not in source(), or native R client

Tags: r, rstudio, rename, plyr

I am using `plyr` to rename the columns of a large data set to a shorter aliases. The from names are very long with occasional unusual symbols (i.e. Â) This code works in in R Studio when I manually (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) execute the code. No errors.

However, when it is run using source in another script and/or in the standard Rgui (even using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), it recognizes some of the names in the from statement, but not others, which are identified in the error:

```
The following from values were not present in x
```

32/64 bit doesn't seem to make a difference. Can't identify character or value that is producing the error. Any solutions?

Should this be posted as an issue on the `plyr` Github?

I have prepared a dummy replica of the data set [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsvnb2ff2jo0rw0/dftest.csv?dl=0).

The program that works in R Studio, but not in standard Rgui is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bze763p7k5ieoza/dftest.R?dl=0).

The code for the "source" call that produces errors is

```
source("dftest.R")
```

All software and packages updated on 3/18/2016.

See similar but unrelated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068960/updated-plyr-rename-not-recognizing-identical-x-error-the-following-from).

Comment: please provide a small subset of data in the text of your question and not as a link; not only does it take a little more effort (that discourage many would-be volunteers), but it is also subject to future [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Same thing for your code: provide a [small](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: @r2evans I'll work on that. 

Also a brief update: Looks like the code works if you copy directly from Rstudio text editor and paste into new Rgui script. But the script won't run, as saved by R studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like copying the code from R Studio text editor and pasting into native client text editor, and then saving, solved both the source problem and the native client problem.